# What does Thanos mean by this?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thanos

When Thanos and Gamora are in Vormir, Thanos says this to Gamora:

> "I ignored my destiny once. I cannot do that again. Even for you."

What does he mean by that? Specifically:

> What was the first occasion where he ignored his destiny?

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88493/what-was-thanos-referring-to

Answer (score 53, accepted):

## When he let Titan die

Thanos reveals in the film that he had proposed a plan to save his people by killing off half the population. This process would be entirely random without prejudice between Rich/Poor, Male/Female, etc. When his plan was rejected, Thanos watched his people suffer and die, making him the *last* or one of the last members of his people.

> Thanos: It was. And it was beautiful. Titan was like most planets: too many mouths, not enough to go around. **And when we faced extinction, I offered a solution.**
> Strange: Genocide.
> Thanos: At random. Dispassionate, fair. Rich and poor alike. **They called me a madman.** And what I predicted came to pass.
> [...]
> Thanos: With all six stones, I could simply snap my fingers and they would all cease to exist. You know what I call that? Mercy.
> Strange: Then what?
> Thanos: I finally rest. **Watch the sun rise on a grateful universe.** The hardest choices require the strongest wills.
> <sub>Marvel's: Infinity War - Transcripts Wiki</sub>

After Thanos had gained some power with an army and begun taking over planets and killing off half their population, he began to see the paradises he created, which is when he realised with the 6 Infinity Stones he would be able to turn the universe into a paradise.

His first mistake was therefore not saving his own people, and as such he decided to save the universe.

Comment: Good answer.  Of course now he has a time stone, so why he couldn't just... well, don't think to hard about it.

Comment: If he would go back and fix it, he wouldn't have the motivation to get the stones, which would mean his return wouldn't happen. it would split timelines.

Comment: @Tschallacka The full IG can avoid any temporal paradoxes.

Comment: @Tschallacka wrong. He doesn't have to go back in time. He can just de-age the whole planet similar to how Doctor Strange did the same thing with the apple in his namesake movie.

Answer (score 13):

Although Edlothiad's answer could make sense, I think what he was referring to specifically is left either to interpretation or for the next movie to clarify. He could have been talking about his people.

But from my understanding, Thanos really did try to save his planet, but did not have the ability/power to do it alone, and nobody was willing to help his plan, so of course the plan was never executed. I don't think that qualify as "ignoring my destiny". If that was what he was referring to, I'd expect a wording along the lines of "I failed at executing my destiny once".

What I think Thanos was referring to was simply him saving Gamora the first time. Although everything went down pretty fast, and I couldn't rewind to make sure, I think Gamora was taken from the "about to die" side of her people, when Thanos "adopted" her. Since he obtained the Soul Stone this way, we can be sure that Thanos really loved her, even if many characters would argue otherwise. So my understanding of that scene was that it was the only time Thanos ever made an exception in his plans, to save Gamora, and it was a really significant event in his life. On that day, he ignored his destiny and chose to save one person who he was supposed to kill.

Then, he realizes that on that day, saving Gamora was not a big dent in his plans, just a negligible difference. But this time, saving her requires him to give up on the entire thing, and prevents him from "saving" the universe. He cannot ignore his destiny again, this time the consequences are several orders of magnitudes bigger. Even for her, the only person he loves, he can't make an exception again.

The movie has very strong utilitarism vs deontologism themes (think about the trolley problem). If we ignore the (very likely) theory that Strange gave out the stone because he saw the future and had to, you can find many instances of "good" characters being unwilling to sacrifice people for the greater good (Wanda and Vision, Strange and Tony, Peter Quill and Gamora), which ultimately leads them to fail, while the "bad" character, Thanos, was willing to do what it takes (kill a loved one) for his idea of the greater good. The big theme was that being nice does not necessarily make you win, as opposed to pretty much every other marvel movie. This time, being the good guy was not enough.

Only one side was willing to do whatever it takes to win, so that side won.

So as for your question, Thanos was simply putting in words his very hard decision to sacrifice everything (to him) for his greater good, his destiny. He chose to save Gamora when the stakes were low, but when the stakes get higher, he can't ignore his destiny this time, and chooses to sacrifice her.

Comment: Agreed; the phrasing that Thanos "let" his planet die is wrong. He tried to save it and was ignored by the people in power.

Comment: Your final paragraph seems to suggest the first several don't answer the question, but instead are a commentary on my answer.

Comment: More like the maniac wanted to save his planet by obliterating it, and they stopped him from making things even worse.

Comment: @DeepS1X Not entirely sure how he could have made things worse than "Literally Everyone is Dead"

Comment: @TylerH Even if it wasn't his fault, he still believes it is. He still blames himself for what he perceives as something he caused, which is a large part of his character

Comment: Kill half the people horrifically now, and then repeat it with the other half later? I'm pretty sure that would be worse than everyone just dying in the end.

Comment: @DeepS1X why would he need to do anything with the other half later? It is confirmed (in-universe), from the words of Thanos, that the plan has worked with other planets later (like Gamora's). Maybe he is delusional about that, but one thing is certain is that he believes it enough to never touch the other half.

Furthermore, real life statistics and population studies tend to show that his plan would actually work, even if the morals are extremely questionable. So it was likely to work, and even if it didn't, Thanos would never touch the other half.

Comment: @Edlothiad I see how that paragraph sounds like that, but I'm not sure how to edit it. The last paragraph was simply a tl;dr of the rest of my answer. Only the first paragraph was intended to address your answer, and I just wanted to explain why I believed a different answer was relevant, even if neither is 100% confirmed

Comment: I'm much more inclined to believe that killing people off to preserve resources just delays the inevitable, and eventually the population springs back and gets right back into the initial problem. So unless you are going to keep culling the population every couple hundred years, (and you find that morally acceptable), it's just a stupid and maniacal plan. Also, I don't think that any real life statistics support genocide as a method of resource control.

Comment: My point is that it is at best a temporary solution, at worst, no solution whatsoever. Also, Gamora's planet was said to not necessarily be lacking in resources in the first place, so it might not have even been a necessary action even if it did work. Certainly not every planet in the universe has exhausted all its resources, not even the majority of them. So the overall plan is just crazy.

Comment: @DeepS1X Except that if you need to cull the population again some couple hundred years later than that is a more fundamental problem. One would imagine that the progression of technology would naturally increase the population the planet can support and considering the Marvel universe has alien planets it's mostly just a matter of expanding the population of Titan beyond Titan. There's a reason he was called mad, y'know, but that doesn't mean it wouldn't actually have solved the immediate population issue. It would.

Comment: Though honestly unless Thanos believed it was imminent universe annihilation due to lack of resources, a much more merciful plan would be to just sterilize half the universe. Can't have kids? Ok, well now the population will naturally dwindle, and we won't have a serious crisis. No need to worry about Thanos if that is literally all he wants the gauntlet for. Nobody will even die if they hand him the gems peacefully. I fully agree with this answer though. Thanos is definitely working under the belief that Gamora is the waver in his destiny once before.